# CodeUI- How can I create a test suite and automatically call the test suite, when the build is green

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a question regarding code UI.

Lets assume that have created bunch of code UI tests (in my case I don't have the test management yet). My questions are:

1) How do we create a test suite from all these coded UI?
2) When the build is green, how we can call either automatically the test suite or call the individual code UI tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more clear, If you are asking how do I run all the test's consecutively, you could make a ordered test file in the project.

What do you mean by "**Call the individual code UI test**", if your just looking to call the test itself click Test-Windows-Test Explorer and you should get a list of Test methods which you can right click and select run.

If you want to run them consecutively you need to look at the start of my answer.

Comment: Lets assume that we have test1,2 and 3. In first iteration, I like to make a suite of test1 and 2. In 2nd iteration Test1, 2 and 3. In 3rd iteration test2 and 3. Now how can I create different suits for different iterations and call them through cmd window (not VS).

Comment: you can make orderedtest files and make them to suit your needs, as far as calling them through CMD i cant help